# Datetime parse "2021-04-20T00:09:14.7724640+02:00"

Tags: c#

Best way to parse `time = "2021-04-20T00:09:14.7724640+02:00"` to valid time. I need seconds as well however once

```
var h = DateTime.ParseExact(time.Substring(14,5), "hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

this returns only hour and minute but I need seconds too, however there is 09:14.7724640+02:00 and if I tried hh:mm:ss the "." throws an "Invalid DateTimet "exception

Comment: Use [`DateTime.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0) or better yet [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-5.0). [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vCRDsi) is a link to a dotnetfiddle showing that it works

Comment: The 'hh:mm:ss' part is 00:09:14.7724640. You forgot about the "00:" part as hours.

Comment: Fundamental question: Do you want a `DateTime` object (i.e something that also contains the *date* and not only the *time* of day), or do you only want a `TimeSpan` object (i.e something that only represents the *time* of day and ignore the date)? Because one of those makes the duplicate close wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string time = "2021-04-20T00:09:14.7724640+02:00";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(time);
```

With this you have the whole string in the `DateTime` object and can do whatever you want with it (e.g. cut out hours, minutes and seconds).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a timespan, datetime also contains a date part.

If you use the following code you will get a `DateTime` an a `TimeSpan`

```
var timeString = "2021-04-20T00:09:14.7724640+02:00";
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(timeString);
var time = dateTime.TimeOfDay;
Console.WriteLine(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy")` and give it the format that you want

```
public static string GetDate(DateTime date)
        {
            return date.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy");
        }
```

Comment: OP has a `string` and wants to parse it to a `DateTime`, not the other way around

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var time = "2021-04-20T00:09:14.7724640+02:00";
var h = DateTime.Parse(time);
var result = h.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```